# How to store a different array for each server in discord js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that blocks swear words by deleting them as soon as they are sent. The bot has a command to add words to the blacklist and it works fine. But the thing I want to do is I want to create a separate blacklist for each server. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and set the key to the Guild ID and value to array of words to blacklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Variable mentioned:

> You can use [`Maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and set the key to the Guild ID and value to array of words to blacklist.

Here's a quick example on how to do that:

```js
const blacklist = new Map();

// the key (message.guild.id), is how you'll be able to reference this element in the future
blacklist.set(message.guild.id, { blacklisted: ['@#$%'] });

// returns array: ['@#$%']
blacklist.get(message.guild.id).blacklisted
```

---

Code Snippet:

```js
const blacklist = new Map();

// the key (message.guild.id), is how you'll be able to reference this element in the future
blacklist.set('example', { blacklisted: ['@#$%'] });

console.log(blacklist.get('example').blacklisted);
blacklist.get('example').blacklisted.push('*&^%');
console.log(blacklist.get('example').blacklisted);

console.log(blacklist.has('notExample'));
```

Comment: I am doing a for loop to see if a message that is sent contains one of the words in the blacklist. How can I implement this? (Note: I had an array called blockedWords and I was  using my add word command to add a word, and the remove command to remove a word from the array.) Is there a way of using it like an array?

Comment: You're still using an array, and everything that worked before will work the same without any changes. The only thing that's different is the method of *getting* the array.

Comment: Hey! I have a problem and I cant seem to figure it out. So when a message is received I set it to contain a default word, so if someone adds a word, it just goes away when another message is received. How can I set it so it only does it once?
Here is my whole code:
https://hastebin.com/vehakiciju.cs

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question, sorry.

Comment: I need to use blacklist.set(message.guild.id, { blacklisted: ['@#$%'] }); in the client.on('message' ..) part because it uses message.guild. But, I am adding words to this  blacklist, and whenever a message is received, it sets it back to default. So if i had blacklist.set(message.guild.id, { blacklisted: ['@#$%'] }) and then I added a word using the add command, lets say test, now it would be blacklisted: ['@#$%', 'test']. But, as i said when a message is received, it sets it back to the default, which is: blacklisted: ['@#$%'] . So the added word gets removed. :)

Comment: (It didnt fit so I am going to continue here)
So I am asking how I can make it save the value test instead of removing it.
I hope I explained it well :)

Comment: Ok, try this. `if (!blacklist.has(message.guild.id) blacklist.set(...)`. This way, it will only set to default if there isn't anything there already

Comment: Glad I could help!